# Where and how to convert data values subject to preferences/unit conversions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, model, dto

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC project with the typical structure/architecture: (thin) controllers, service layer, repositories. We're using DTOs to hit the service layer and afterwards model/entities.

The application deals with weight and distance fields that can be displayed according to user's preferences (metric or imperial system). These values are always persisted using the metric system so these values are being converted (if necessary) when displayed and when entered by user. This is currently being done in the service layer, which handles the mapping between entities and DTOs and vice-versa and converters these fields as well (if preference is imperial system). For example, in a GET scenario this unit conversion is being handled (manually) as a post step after mapping to DTO and per entity.

As the application grows this is getting boring and not really optimal so wanted to get some ideas regarding the following:

- The decision/idea is that from the service layer down, the system always deals with metric system because user preferences is kind of a GUI detail and shouldn't be factored in the model. So the unit conversion is being done at the service layer. Any comments if this is the best place to perform this? I wouldn't like to perform this in the Controllers because in the near future we plan to have as well a mobile app and the service layer should be common.
- The unit conversion (helper methods) is currently being done manually, let's say, after mapping to DTO (if getting info) and per entity. I'd like to get some ideas on how could I make this step a bit more automated or better designed? Maybe mark the properties that can subject to conversion with an attribute and somehow pick that up and convert automatically but I can't seem to find a good idea for this. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you look some libraries like AutoMapper?

Comment: I can use AutoMapper but my issue is not with the mapping but with the actual value conversion (metric to imperial) and how I can accomplish this with less specific code for each entity. With Automapper I'd have to still manually do it for each property right?